# I can't join my class group chat because of iPad users who require iMessage

Tags: sms, ios, google-messages

I'm trying to join my class's group chat, but the owner of the chat (on iOS) can't add me. This is because I'm the only person on Android in the group. Normally I would be able to join (via SMS/MMS) but because many of my classmates are on iPads which only support iMessage it won't let him add me. Is there a way that I can be added to the group chat that preferably doesn't require any of the members (besides the owner) to change or do anything? BTW I don't own any Apple devices or have an Apple account/ID.

Comment: Tell that your teacher and ask to switch to an open messaging solution that is not locked-in to the Apple world like Signal. Alternatively the other pupils can provide you an iPhone/iPad if they refuse to switch...

Comment: The chat is managed by students and is for non-school related conversations. The other users are unlikely to switch the platform because I'm currently the only users not on iOS.

Comment: Then you can only talk to them if they understand that by they exclude you and why they do it this way. May be you can mention that because of iCloud sync Apple can read all their messages and if they are really happy with that.

Comment: Please take a look at the duplicate question. iMessage is an Apple proprietary technology. Unfortunately, that means that only Apple products can use it.